# Discord API Gif Avatars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, discord, gif

Im making a discord bot dashboard, Id like it if when there logged in it shows them their avatar. Ive successfully got that working however it. This is my react code:

```
<div>
  {user.avatar === 'null' ?
     <img onClick={toggleMenu} src={discord} width="40px" height="40px" className="uimg" />
  :
     <img onClick={toggleMenu} src={`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${user.discordId}/${user.avatar}.png`} width="40px" height="40px" className="uimg" />
  }
</div>
```

This makes their avatar appear. If their avatar is a gif I want it to animate like a gif. I know I can just put `${user.avatar}.gif` instead of `png` but then png images won't show up. Does anyone know how to test if their avatar is a gif??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!!

instead of this

```
 <img onClick={toggleMenu} src={`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${user.discordId}/${user.avatar}.png`} width="40px" height="40px" className="uimg" />
```

I will remove the `.png` like this:

```
 <img onClick={toggleMenu} src={`https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/${user.discordId}/${user.avatar}`} width="40px" height="40px" className="uimg" />
```